# Files are corrupted or Unreachable in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Today when i open my android studio i found a weird thing that **.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\recyclerview-v7-27.0.0.aar\58f87e603e61efa166446f59b7ffbceb\jars: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.**. I tried Invalidate cache and Restart, Clean and rebuild project. Nothing has worked. [image: Error image]

Comment: Can you try to delete the folder and resync?

Comment: Try to remove and add dependency than sync

Comment: Or try this Go to "File" and click on "Invalid caches\ Restart" option  on android studio

Comment: which folder i have to delete @Edric?

Comment: I already done "Invalidate caches\Restart" restarted android studio for multiple times... @RahulChokshi

Answer (score 0):

Go to C drive /Users/"Ypur PC Name"/  and delete .android , .AndroidStudio"version" , .cache , .crashlytics , .gradle folders

Comment: Yeah problem got solved. Just deleted the Lock file in that folder